# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''　Can't I cast int to None?

Tags: python, django

I got an error,ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' .
I wrote

```
def convert_json(request):
    id = None
    print(type(id))
    json_body = json.loads(request.body)
    for index, content in json_body.items():
        if index == "ans":
            id = content
    id = int(id)

    return id
```

When json_body does not have "ans" key,id has None and the error happens in the code of `id = int(id)` .`print(type(id))` print out class 'str' so I really cannot understand why I cannot convert str into int.Is None special kind of str?I wanna put empty value to id when json_body does not have "ans" key.How should I fix this?

Comment: No, the `ValueError` occurs when `id` is a non-numerical string. Otherwise a `TypeError` would be raised: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: Have you tried printing out the 'id' to see what it is? If it is not a string defining a number you'll get the ValueError.

Comment: `Is None special kind of str?` no, it is not.
`I wanna put empty value to id` And what integer you believe should represent that "empty value"? (ie, if `id` is None what do you expect `int(id)` to return?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is rather strange. The result of `json.loads` is a dictionary; the point of a dictionary is that you can access keys directly, there is no need to iterate. The other advantage is that you can use `.get()` with a default. So you should just do:

```
def convert_json(request):
    json_body = json.loads(request.body)
    return json_body.get('ans', 0)
```

Comment: thx,ur answer.I wrote ur codes,and when I send json like  `{
    "ans": ""
} ` same error happens.Why can't this program put 0?How can I fix this?